Word add-in: Show external API call response in Taskpane?
I've developed a simple Word Add-in which calls an external API with the selected text from the right-click menu. I can then insert the response on the Document, by I'd rather show the response on the taskpane.
I've tried adding a placeholder div on the taskpane, and then modifying the innerHtml from the commands.js function which calls the API, but it doesn't work. It seems like commands.js (which holds the right click menu function) cannot directly modify the taskpane? How do I overcome this?
